# woocommerce поиск по фильтрам

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter

Ищу способы реализации вот такого фильтра, пользователь выбирает производителя, затем в зависимости от выбранного производителя подбираются модели, затем год и уже цена, а при нажатии на кнопку поиска, автоматически пересылает на архив товаров с подобранными фильтрами.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

важное примечание: страницы single-page/content-single-page нет! они не используются, так что редирект на найденную модель крайне нежелателен.

Comment: Да, и нужно чтобы оформление фильтра можно было настроить точно такое же

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень не плохой плагин для фильтра товара, фильтрует по атрибутам, а отрибуты выставляете какие захотите называется плагин:
WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter
Советую почитать про него и разобратся
Очень полезная вещь